# Number of iterations in NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

In Excel's solver, one can define how many iterations are to be done, to one's liking.

I am wondering if this is possible to do with [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html) in *Mathematica*?

**Code**

This is what I'm working with:

```
A = 3580/1000; (*constante*)
B = 736/1000;(*constante*)
R1 = 5/1000;(*0-1.5*)
R2 = 17/1000;(*0-1.5*)

fR1 = ((A + B) (1 - a)^2 (1/15 + P2/21 - (4 P4)/35))/
    (A (1/15 (3 + 4 a + 8 a^2) + 4/21 (3 + a - 4 a^2) P2 + 
      8/35 (1 - a)^2 P4) + B (1 - a)^2 (1/15 + P2/21 - (4 P4)/35));
fR2 = (A (1 - a)^2 (1/15 + P2/21 - (4 P4)/35) + B (1 - a)^2 (1/15 - (2 P2)/21 + P4/35))/
    (A (1/15 (3 + 4 a + 8 a^2) - 2/21 (3 + a - 4 a^2) P2 + 
      3/35 (1 - a)^2 P4) + B (1 - a)^2 (1/15 - (2 P2)/21 + P4/35));
fP4 = -((83 P2)/1000) + (1366 P2^2)/1000 - (1899 P2^3)/1000 + (1616 P2^4)/1000;
fRho = ((A + B) (1 - a)^2)/(A (8 a^2 + 4 a + 3) + B (1 - a)^2);

NSolve[R1 == fR1 && R2 == fR2 && P4 == fP4 && rho == fRho, {P2, P4, a, rho}, Reals];
MatrixForm[%]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main algorithm behind `NSolve` is, I believe, the Jenkins-Traub algorithm, which is indeed iterative in nature.  I don't believe that you can specifiy the number of iterates directly, however.  Isn't it better to specify the desired precision, though?  Mathematica tries to find the solution to a certain precision, and you can specify the precision that you want, as in

```
eqs = {R1==fR1, R2==fR2, P4==fP4, rho==fRho};
sols= NSolve[eqs, {P2, P4, a, rho}, Reals,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20];
```

You can always check the quality of the results, as well, using something like so:

```
(#[[1]] - #[[2]] & /@ eqs) /. sols
```

This will let you know exactly how close you are on each equation.

Comment: I'm asking this on behalf of a colleague who's wondering if the algorithm could stop when it finds a local minimum, thus missing the global one. Since we're looking for intersecting points, I can't see how that situation could happen with `NSolve`, but maybe I'm wrong. Would that be possible?

Comment: @CHM I believe that the answer to that question is No. At least the algorithm is designed to be a global solver with a global stopping criterion. Again, even if one is not sure, it's very easy to plug back in to check the quality of the solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I had suggested to augment the `WorkingPrecision`, but the data apparently still didn't meet the expectations. It seems like the model has found its limits!

Comment: @CHM Really? I get differences on the order of 10^(-20) or less on each equation.

Comment: The equations are modeling physical phenomena. This model is a new one adopted by my colleague, the data obtained is compared to an older, proven one, as well as experimental data. The problem is not with _Mathematica_, but with the model. The discrepancies occur a bit too early in the predicted limits of the model, which prompted my colleague to make me check if it was MMA's fault :P

Comment: @CHM Ah, I see - very interesting!

Comment: If memory serves, Jenkins-Traub is a three-pronged approach: stage 1 takes a fixed number of iterations, and there is some cycling between stages two and three, depending on the conditioning of the root being sought. The termination is tricky, and is not dependent on iteration count. I would guess this is why `NSolve[]` doesn't take an option for an iteration ceiling...

Comment: `FindRoot[]`, however, does take a `MaxIterations` option...

Answer (score 8):

From [this documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#25940),

> "For systems of algebraic equations, `NSolve` computes a numerical
>   Gröbner basis using an efficient monomial ordering, then uses
>   eigensystem methods to extract numerical roots."

When one restricts to work over the reals this is no longer necessarily how it is done. In any case, `NSolve` is not using iterative methods. (In particular it is not using Jenkins-Traub, because that only applies to univariate polynomials.) Upshot: One cannot limit the iterations. Also I'll confirm that for polynomial systems (or rational functions), `NSolve` does in fact find all solutions (barring extreme numerical instability).

About the `WorkingPrecision` option. It does not do much to guarantee the precision of the output. It can be used to force high precision. This can be helpful in cases where the eigensystem extraction is not well behaved, or where high precision is really needed to get small residuals due to instability of the inputs. (How might one know? By checking the results from running `NSolve` without setting that option, and noticing fairly large residuals.)

Comment: Sorry for asking here in a comment, but could you by any chance suggest a good introductory learning resource about Gröbner bases?

Comment: ["Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms" by Cox, Little, O'Shea (Springer Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics)](http://www.springerlink.com/content/l54645/). Also there is "An Introduction to Gröbner Bases" by Adams and Loustaunau (AMS Graduate Studies in Mathematics).

Comment: @Szabolcs: [Here](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~dac/iva.html) is their webpage; if you're going to be solving a lot of multivariate algebraic equations, learning how Gröbner works will be profitable. See also [this math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550).

Comment: Thanks @J.M.!  The book can be downloaded [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/l54645/) (if your university is a subscriber).